# (22.10) "include applications from each monitor only" setting in "settings" -> "multitasking" does not work

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, workspaces, application-switcher

Under `settings` -> `multitasking` there is an option all the way at the end under `application switching` titled `Include applications from each monitor only`.

Expected behavior, from what it sounds like, is that when alt-tabbing, only the applications in the *current monitor* appear. The option right above it whether to `Include applications from the current workspace only` or not, and that's how that one behaves. Instead, nothing changes from what I can see. Applications only on one monitor still show up in the other monitor when alt-tabbing.

On Nvidia, so using X, not sure if that has any bearing on it.

Thanks!

Comment: Noticed that it gets rid of the taskbar icons on the other monitor. So if you have an application open in a different monitor only, the icon for that application won't appear in the taskbar. I'm guessing it's a bug that alt-tabbing includes it.